# python get html page after login

Tags: python, html, authentication, python-requests

I want to login to famjia.com and i try all the methods, none of them works for me. I tried using requests and urllib but they don't work. Help? These is my code. Thanks in advance.
    import requests

```
URL = 'http://www.famjia.com/portal/intranet/famjiaPaper/'

session = requests.session()

login_data = dict({'initialURI':'/portal/intranet/',
                           'loginname':'loginname',
                           'loginpassword':'loginpassword',
                           'username':'username',
                           'password':'password',

                          })
r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

req = session.get('http://www.famjia.com/portal/intranet/famjiaPaper/')

print req.content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `POST` request should be made to `http://www.famjia.com/portal/login` url:

```
import requests

URL = 'http://www.famjia.com/portal/intranet/famjiaPaper/'
LOGIN_URL = 'http://www.famjia.com/portal/login'

session = requests.session()

login_data = {'initialURI': '/portal',
              'loginname': '',
              'loginpassword': '',
              'username': 'YOUR USERNAME HERE',
              'password': 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE'}
session.post(LOGIN_URL, data=login_data)

req = session.get(URL)
print req.content
```